# Should there be two html doctype declarations on one page?

Tags: html, xhtml, doctype

I am working migrating a clients site to xml/xsl,
they have two HTML Doctypes on one page..

Is this wrong or is there a reason they may have done this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sections 7.1 and 7.2 of the HTML 4.01 spec speak about *one* HTML document type declaration:

- Section 7.1 says: "...**a line** containing HTML version information".
- Section 7.2 says: "...authors must include **one** of the following document type declarations in their documents".

See [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html) for details.

Answer (score 2):

No there shouldn't be.